# Cannot change UIImageView image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an `IBOutlet` to `UIImageView` called `attachmentImage`. By default it has a placeholder image added through storyboard.

If image is already present it is displayed using `setImageWithURL`. This works and displays image. Called from `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.attachmentImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:attachmentImageURL]];
self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.attachmentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
[attachmentImage setNeedsDisplay];
```

If image is not present it is chosen from library and added like so;

```
- (void)takeController:(FDTakeController *)controller gotPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [attachmentImage setImage:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.attachmentImage setImage:photo];
    self.attachmentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [attachmentImage setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The upload works if there was no image already added (apart from the placeholder). But if image view has image set with `setImageWithURL` that image is not replaced.

Why is this happening? HELP!

**EDIT** Now image does change but reverts back after a second or two. This is the change I made to the `setImageWithURL` function;

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            attachmentImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, imgpath];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:attachmentImageURL];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

            if (![data isEqualToData:nil]) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    attachmentImage.image = image;
                    self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                    self.attachmentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    [attachmentImage setNeedsDisplay];

                    [self applyImageViewConstraints];
                });
            }

        });
```

So close.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to have, and what do you have actually? And can you also post some screenshot?

Comment: You are getting image from server??

Comment: I think that maybe your viewDidload has been called after you've set new image. Separate the code that set the default image (in your viewDidload) then add a NSLog() to know whenever it got called.

Comment: You say that it reverts after 2 seconds, have you checked that your setImageWithURL isn't being called many times? particularly the attachmentImage.image = image;

Comment: it is not. Solved it. Adding answer. Don't know what caused the issue though. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, cannot figure out what was wrong though. Something to do with queues :/

From `viewDidLoad` :

```
attachmentImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, imgpath];
        NSLog(@"the image url is %@", attachmentImageURL);
        [self.attachmentImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:attachmentImageURL]];
        self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.attachmentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [attachmentImage setNeedsDisplay];
        [self applyImageViewConstraints];
```

And the upload method.

```
- (void)takeController:(FDTakeController *)controller gotPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSLog(@"In takeController");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{attachmentImage.image = nil;});

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{attachmentImage.image = photo;});
    self.attachmentImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    selectedImage = photo;

    [self applyImageViewConstraints];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would try first removing the setNeedsDisplay - not needed for UIImageView in most cases

if this doesn't work, it seems that the first part of your code is run for some reason before the second part. i would put some logging calls to check what is the real order of execution.

if all else fails, you can implement an really hacky solution by delaying the call..

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC),    
dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ .... }
```

also if this solves it, it can give you a clue of some unexpected code running inside those 2 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can clean a lot your code.

I don't know if I understand what do you want but try implementing this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.attachmentImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; // You can also select the content mode in the storyboard
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        attachmentImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, imgpath];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:attachmentImageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (data) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.attachmentImage.image = image;
            });
        }else{
            // Do something
        }

    });
}
```

Maybe the image reverts because you invoke the method `- (void)takeController:(FDTakeController *)controller gotPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;` too early.

Answer (score 0):

I think the delegate method

```
- (void)takeController:(FDTakeController *)controller gotPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

You are saying about is called before image is set in imageview url.
So you can either try to get know when this method is called or for the time being you can call the delegate method explicitly like:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        attachmentImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, imgpath];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:attachmentImageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (data) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.attachmentImage.image = image;
            });
        }else{
            // Do call delegate method with needed arguments supplied

[fdTakeController.delegate takeController:controller gotPhoto:photo withInfo:info ];

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a weird behavior, maybe the call to **setImageWithURL** delays the execution of the code that sets the image (if it does exist), maybe you could try [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/) and change your **setImageWithURL** to something like this:

```
// In your class definition
PMKPromise* setImageFromURLPromise;

// In your implementation
-(void) setImageWithURL {
     _setImageFromURLPromise = [NSURLConnection GET:@[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BaseURL, imgpath]].then(^(UIImage *image) {
        self.attachmentImage.image = image;
    }).catch(^(NSError *error){
        // error handling if needed?
    });
}
```

And before actually trying to load the photo from the camera/photo library you could check:

```
if (setImageFromURLPromise == nil || [setImageFromURLPromise resolved]) {
   // The promise is resolved, no more race conditions or rare behavior, take the photo or load from the library.
} else {
   // Display a message that the image from URL is still loading...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem is that it takes time to download image from URL.
In this case I would use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or already mentioned [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/).

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) allows caching images as well.